# асинхронное выполнение пинга

Tags: c#, .net, windows, асинхронность

Пробую так:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            Task<IPStatus> t = ping(dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString());
            t.Wait();
            dataGridView1[1, i].Value = t.Result;
        }
    }

    async Task<IPStatus> ping(string address)
    {
        IPAddress IP = null;
        IPAddress.TryParse(address,out IP);
        PingReply pr = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(IP);
        return pr.Status;
    }
```

Отладка становиться на функции SendPingAsync(IP) и она выполняется до бесконечности. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас дедлок, так как асинхронный метод ждет сам себя и не может вернуться в UI поток. Попробуйте так:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        IPStatus t = await ping(dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString());
        dataGridView1[1, i].Value = t;
    }
}

async Task<IPStatus> ping(string address)
{
    IPAddress IP = null;
    IPAddress.TryParse(address,out IP);
    PingReply pr = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(IP);
    return pr.Status;
}
```

Comment: И за это тоже спасибо )