# Как правильно проверять наличие интернета асинхронно

Tags: c#

в моем предложении нужно проверять наличие интернета, как правильно периодически проверить. Пинг это хорошо или нет.

Comment: Смотря что вы подразумеваете под наличием интернета

Comment: [асинхронный пинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884108/%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0/884111#884111)?

Comment: @АндрейNOP мне нужно парсить сайт, и мне нужно проверить доступен ли он или нет по хттп протолку.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch так выполните запрос к сайту, если ответ придет без ошибок - то доступен