# Как записать найденные ip адреса в локальной сети, в List<string>?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ip

Всем привет!

Я получила список доступных ip адресов в локальной сети. Мне нужно сохранить их в лист для дальнейшего использования. Но сохранить в лист через pingcomplited не получается. Как можно это сделать?

Вот часть моего кода:

Объявляю глобально

```
private List<string> servers = new List<string>();
```

После чего идёт асинхронный пинг (функция FindServers)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
            {
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipBase + i);

                System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();

                ping.PingCompleted += p_PingCompleted;
                PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);
                ping.SendAsync(ip, 100, buffer, options, waiter);
            }
```

И p_PingCompleted

```
if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            //**в консоль выводится без проблем**
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Ping successed on IP: " + e.Reply.Address.ToString());

            //**вот здесь пытаюсь сохранить в лист, но он всегда остаётся пустым**
            servers.Add("Ping successed on IP: " + e.Reply.Address.ToString());

            //продолжает главный поток
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }
```

**UPDATE:** Функция ClientStart, вызывается при запуске игры

```
private void ClientStart()
    {
        FindServers();

        if (servers.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < servers.Count; i++)
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(servers[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("nope");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что значит остаётся пустым? Как вы это проверяете? Покажите код.

Comment: Скорее всего вы проверяете список еще до того как в него было что-либо записано. Еще `List` не является потокобезопасным, лучше использовать например `lock`, чтобы не повредить его при записи из разных потоков.

Comment: @tym32167 обновила. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Если чего-то не хватает - дополню.

Comment: @aepot спасибо. Я пробовала ставить lock в p_PingCompleted в проверку. И внутри lock записывать в list. Это не помогло. Могу скинуть код, как я это делала, если это поможет.

Comment: Лучше и проще использовать метод `SendPingAsync`, который возвращает Task.

Comment: [асинхронное выполнение пинга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884111/179763) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, потокобезопасность

```cs
lock (servers)
    servers.Add("Ping successed on IP: " + e.Reply.Address.ToString());
```

Во-вторых, вы пытаетесь прочитать список до того как он будет пополнен.

Заведите счетчик

```cs
private int pingCount;
```

И увеличивайте его

```cs
if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    // ...
}
int count = Interlocked.Increment(ref pingCount);
if (count == 255)
{
    // все пинги закончились, здесь и надо выполнять код чтения списка, или не раньше, чем вы попадете сюда
    if (servers.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < servers.Count; i++)
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(servers[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("nope");
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, вы мне очень помогли. Но мне нужно использовать лист за пределами p_PingCompleted. Не подскажите, как это можно сделать? Я пытаюсь проверить количество элементов в листе в главной функции, которая вызывается при старте программы. Но в листе пусто. Я понимаю, что дело в потоках, но не знаю, как можно получить элементы листа после выполнения пинга.

Comment: @Claire вы можете использовать его где угодно. Вся проблема только в том, когда это делать, а делать это надо не раньше, чем закончится последний пинг, а не сразу после запуска пингов, когда в список еще не успело ничего заиисаться. Здесь нет никакой магии и с самим списком все в порядке.

Comment: так как же узнать, что последний пинг закончился?

Comment: @Claire `if (count == 255)` вам точно ни о чем не говорит? Он как раз проверяет счетчик, считающий пинги. Я же вам дал готовый код, очень странно, что вы этого не заметили.

Comment: так ```if (count == 255)``` используется внутри p_PingCompleted. 
Если создать глобальный bool и объявить его false, а внутри блока проверки ```if (count == 255)``` менять его значение на true, то его значение за пределами p_PingCompleted остаётся false (вероятно, потому что при проверке переменной ещё не выполнился пинг). 

Т.е., у меня есть функция, которая выполняет пинг ClientStart(), в ней выполняется p_PingCompleted в цикле. Сам ClientStart запускается в main. И после выполнения ClientStart, в Main должен быть заполненный список. Но он остаётся пустым.

Comment: @Claire Вы можете внутри проверки вызвать другой метод, я не понимаю в чем проблема. Никаких булов не нужно.

Comment: а ведь и правда ) спасибо, не понимаю, как не подумала об этом варианте. До вашего комментария я просто перетащила весь нужный мне код внутрь проверки, но почему-то не додумалась, что можно просто объявить внутри функцию )